# Windows Command line append to xml files based on key value pairs

Tags: xml, windows, command-line, key-value

I have a bunch of xml files named content_[0-9] (content underscore followed by a single digit) in  a bunch of seperate directories. These files all have a single airport_code element like so:

```
<airport_code>JFK</airport_code>
```

I then have a key value mappings like so:

```
JFK=US/Eastern
LHR=Europe/London
etc
```

I want to cycle through all these xml files and append the correct timezone element to each xml file, so that the JFK file would read:

```
<airport_code>JFK</airport_code> 
<timezone>US/Eastern</timezone>
```

Im trying to do this in a windows batch script (with [unix utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) installed). Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off 
for /d %%x in (C:\directory\*) do type %%x\content_? | grep "<airport_code>" | gawk "{gsub(/  <airport_code>/, \"\"); print}" | gawk "{gsub(/<\/airport_code>/, \"\"); print}"
```

Which will read the airport codes of all the xml files out.

How would I look upp the value in my key-value pair for each airport code and append the appropriate timezone element? Is this possible? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it in batch but this feels like a WSH/JScript job to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this on my own, but only by switching over to the powershell. Comments  and improvements are appreciated, as are suggestions for doing things within cmd:

```
foreach ($i in get-childitem $loc -recurse){
    if ($i.name -match "content_"){
        $content = get-content $i.FullName
        $airportcode=get-content $i.FullName | select-string -pattern "<airport_code>"
        $airportcode= $airportcode -replace "<airport_code>", "" 
        $airportcode= $airportcode -replace "</airport_code>", ""
        $airportcode= $airportcode -replace "  ", ""
        $timezone=$timezones.Get_Item("$airportcode")
        $newContent = $content -replace "</airports>", ""
        $newContent = $newContent -replace "  ","`n  "
        $newContent="$($newContent)`n<timezone>$($timezone)</timezone>`n</airports>"
        Set-Content $i.FullName $newContent
    } 
}
```

note that this also removes the closing element tag </airports> and then appends it to the document at the end.